# Converting NSString to NSAttribtuedString for Drawing

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have a string that is being drawn with the code

`[@"-" drawInRect: r
                withFont: f2
           lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
               alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];`

However I want to change the color in this string, since this is not possible with NSString I wish to modify it to an NSAttributedString.

However this isn't working, here is my modified code, I couldn't find the attributes for the other parameters as well

```
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:f2,NSFontAttributeName,
                                        nil];

    NSAttributedString *drawingString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:@"-" attributes:attrsDictionary];

    [drawingString drawInRect:r];
```

Any Help is appreciated whether this is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` property as well.

Here's a [complete list](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688) - in the Constants section:

```
NSString *const NSFontAttributeName;
NSString *const NSParagraphStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSForegroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSBackgroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSLigatureAttributeName;
NSString *const NSKernAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrokeColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrokeWidthAttributeName;
NSString *const NSShadowAttributeName;
NSString *const NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName;
```

Comment: Any idea how I can duplicate the textalignment and linebreakmode attributes?

Comment: Ah I found it in NSParagraphStyle, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! Here's my final edited code

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraAttr = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle ] mutableCopy];
    [paraAttr setAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [paraAttr setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:f2,NSFontAttributeName,
                                        [UIColor grayColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                        paraAttr,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                         nil];


    NSAttributedString *drawingString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:@"•" attributes:attrsDictionary];


    [drawingString drawInRect:r];
```